# Retrofit-2.0 - Parse response having json within xml

Tags: android, json, xml, converters, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2.0 and i want to parse a custom response.
The POST request contains json format. while response is combination of both xml and json.
example request:

```
{"loginid":"10051"}
```

example response:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.example.com/">{"user":"user1", "class":"1"}</string>
```

so,
I want to get json part `{"user":"user1", "class":"1"}` from the response.

I tried to write custom converter. But As I am new to Retrofit 2.0, unable to write.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try convert it to `JsonElement` object, but do not convert it after that to `JsonObject` or `JsonArray`, because you will see exception for sure. After that call `.toString` method and parse with whatever you want your response.

Some interface for receive RequestBody as response:

```
@POST("/exampleRout")
    Call<JsonElement> foo(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

Response:

```
 public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
       JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
       String yourResponseString = jsonElement.toString();
       //parse it with regEx or XML parser and etc
}
```